# NewRelic: XML instrumentation not appears in NewRelic

Tags: xml, newrelic

I implemented XML instrumentation and I do see the classes and their methods in the NewRelic log displayed as "Instrumenting class" + the class names and also "Traced" + the class names.
The methods show up in the log as "Matched method"+ method name+ "for instrumentation". So I think my XML file gets picked up ok.
On the NewRelic "transactions" page I'm expecting to see these classes in the "Breakdown table" when I select the transaction utilizing the classes I'm expecting to see.
But I don't see them in the the "Breakdown table" or anywhere else.

When I switched the log level from "finer" back to "info", I noticed the following error:

```
Oct 2, 2015 14:42:50 -0700 NewRelic 1 ERROR: com/caucho/vfs/WriteStream is marked as a weaved class, but no methods are matched to be weaved.
```

I'm not sure if I should ignore the error since the transaction does appear and from looking around online I noticed this error shows up in a variety of situations... 
I would like to be able to see the methods from my XML file in the "Breakdown table", but I have no idea what I'm missing here. Below, I'm posting my XML file. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extension xmlns="https://newrelic.com/docs/java/xsd/v1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="newrelic-extension extension.xsd " name="cmsPublish" version="1.0" enabled="true">
  <instrumentation metricPrefix="CMS Listeners">

    <pointcut transactionStartPoint="true" excludeFromTransactionTrace="false" ignoreTransaction="false">
        <className>com.cms.listener.freewheel.FreeWheelListener</className>
        <method>
            <name>post</name>
        </method>
        <method>
                <name>getXMLOutput</name>
        </method>
    </pointcut>

    <pointcut transactionStartPoint="true" excludeFromTransactionTrace="false" ignoreTransaction="false">
        <className>com.cms.listener.ramp.RAMPListener</className>                
        <method>
            <name>post</name>
        </method>
        <method>
            <name>publishContentPerformed</name>
        </method>
    </pointcut>
  </instrumentation>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me awhile to realize that I was looking in a wrong place to see my custom detail. My targeted classes are under Non-Web transactions, under the name I gave them... I only wish NewRelic installation pages had a better note on how to find what you target, would have saved me 1 day of development.